# JAVA: Why does my return error during compile?

Tags: java, return, try-catch

I inherited some code that's erroring out on me when I compile. I get one of two errors: One, that the `return` statement is missing, or another that I have a mismatched `throw`/`try`/`catch`. This error *seems* to be related to the position of `return` statement, which I've been moving around all morning. Its current position yields `error: missing return statement`. Either of the returns that are commented out yield a message that I must declare a `try` or `catch` with my `throw`.

Consider:

```
static private List<File> getFileListingNoSort(File aDirectory) throws FileNotFoundException {

try {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] filesAndDirs = aDirectory.listFiles();
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
    for(File file : filesDirs) {
         result.add(file); //always add, even if directory
         if ( ! file.isFile() ) {
              List<File> deeperList = getFileListingNoSort(file);
              result.addAll(deeperList);
           // return result;
         } //close if
      // return result;
     } // close for
     } // close try for getFileListingNoSort
   // return result;
 catch (Exception exp) {
      System.err.println("Error: " + exp.getMessage());
 } //close catch getFileListingNoSort
 return result;
} //close method
```

I would *think* that the return would go after the try, but before the catch. However, that didn't work for me. I'm not really sure WHY I'm getting the areas, other than a misunderstanding of how the program is flowing with the `try`/`catch`. Can someone tell me the most appropriate place for the return and explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method has to return ALWAYS, either normally, or by issuing an Exception.

In case your `catch` clause doesn't throw an `Exception`, you need a `return` statement either as the last statement of the catch, or after the catch.

When you want to return something outside your try block, it's value must be defined *before* you go in the try.

For instance, if you want to return some value in the try (in case all goes well), and null if you get an Exception, your code would look something like this:

```
try{
   ... do loads of stuff
   return value;
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //log it, whatever
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
try {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
```

do

```
List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
try {
```

this way the variable `result` will not be out of scope after the `try/catch` block.

The list will contain every element added up to until the exception occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `result` inside your try block, but (trying to) return it outside of the block. This won't work because the variable is then out of scope. The simplest way to fix this is to declare the result variable outside of the try block.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is in try block, and it could be not-initialized. Taking it outside of the try block will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your trying to access `result` variable that waht declared in `try` block and will not be visible out of it.